# Excel VBA how to search through 2d array

Tags: excel, vba

Basically I am trying to Loop through all the values in the array and count the number of values that are greater than a value specified by the user by using Inputbox and also trying to use the IF statement to ensure a number between 1 and 100 is entered. After that is done I just want to simply display the results in a message box after.

Here is what I have so far:

```
Dim arr As Variant
arr = Range("A1:J10")

Range("A1").Resize(UBound(arr, 1), UBound(arr, 2)) = arr

Dim val As String
val = InputBox("Enter an integer value")
If val < 1 Or val > 100 Then
' tells the user to try again
    MsgBox "You did not enter a value from 1 to 100 , try again"
val = Inputbox("Enter an integer value")
Else

End If
```

Basically struggling with the if statement to verify the contents entered by the user and looping through the array.

Comment: I assume you want an `or` in the if statement as `val` cannot be both less than one and greater than 100.

Comment: ah right good point!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim val As String
val = InputBox("Enter an integer value")

Do While val < 1 Or val > 100
' tells the user to try again
    MsgBox "You did not enter a value from 1 to 100 , try again"
    val = InputBox("Enter an integer value")
Loop

'checks array if the number is greater then input number
Dim MyRange As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim counter as integer
counter = 0
Set MyRange = Range("A1:J10")
For Each cell In MyRange
  If cell.Value > CInt(val) Then
    counter = counter + 1
    cell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) 'or cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
  End If
Next

msgbox "Total number greater then input number is: " & counter
```

Comment: would there be a way to verify val with only using an If/Else statement?

Comment: why do you insist on using if statement when a loop would be better in my opinion.

Comment: Because I was going to use another loop which will count the values in the array greater than the one entered in val. was trying to avoid having a loop in a loop in this case

Comment: try the answer i posted to see if it does what you need.

Comment: should i do Dim cell As Range to avoid another that is popping up?

Comment: I've just modified the code. It looks in all your column ranges and see if it is greater then your val input, if it is, it counts it and msgbox the total count after the loop is done.

Comment: It is suppose to work but the error for "cell" keeps popping up, suggesting something to do with this line:  For Each cell In MyRange

Comment: Yes, i forgot to declare it because on mine i didn't turn on option explicit therefore don't see the error.

Comment: If i want to addtionally loop through all the values in the range A1:J10 and shades all the values larger than val to like red, would I just do Do While arr > val then cell.Interior.Color = rgb(255,0,0) ?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the following, which gets rid of loops and arrays all together by using the built-in `CountIF` function.

```
Do

    Dim val As Variant
    val = InputBox("Enter an integer value")

    If IsNumeric(val) And val > 1 And val < 100 Then

        Dim bPass As Boolean
        bPass = True

    End If

    If Not bPass Then MsgBox "You did not enter a value from 1 to 100 , try again"

Loop Until bPass

Dim lCountIf As Long

lCountIf = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A1:J10"), ">" & val)

MsgBox lCountIf & " values greater than " & val & "in Range."
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd

- use Application.InputBox() which lets you force a numeric input
- avoid array and use WorksheetFunction.CountIf()

As follows:

```
Dim val As Integer

Do
    val = CInt(Application.InputBox(prompt:="Enter an integer value between 1 and 100", Type:=1))
Loop while val <1 And val > 100

MsgBox WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A1:J10"), ">" & val)
```

Comment: I was looking for that (`Application.InputBox`). My memory failed me on what the correct syntax was ... so I thought my memory just failed me on InputBox being able to force an integer :(

Comment: @ScottHoltzman, yeah it's something useful. I even prefer it to `IsNumeric()` since this latter isn't reliable (e.g.: `?IsNumeric("1..2")` returns `True`...)